# Does the parity of the identity of a group hold any known significance?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, parity

I understand that for permutation groups, the parity of identity is even.

However when considering, for example $\langle\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}, \cdot\rangle$ where $\cdot$ is regular multiplication, the identity is *odd*.

Does the parity of the identity tell us anything about the group or the operation?

Comment: Use `$\langle x\rangle$` for $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: Note that $0$ has no multiplicative inverse, so cannot be in that group.

Comment: $\langle \mathbb{Z}, \cdot \rangle$ is not a group, The integers don't have multiplicative inverses (in the integers).

Comment: $\langle \mathbb Z,\cdot\rangle$ isn’t a group? Parity of a permutation is very different from parity of a group element’s order, fwiw.

Comment: Sorry about that, let me change my example.

Comment: Again, zero cannot be in that "group".

Comment: Basically, parity in finite symmetric groups does not generalize to general groups. All finite groups are isomorphic to some subgroup of a symmetric group, but we can actually make the parity of all the elements in the image even. Even given the smallest $n$ such that $S_n$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $G,$ parity is still not well-defined. For example, $G=C_2\times C_2$ has a lot of isomorphism with subgroups of $S_4,$ and the parities of the images of the elements vary depending on the isomorphism.

Comment: $\langle\mathbb Q,\cdot\rangle$ is not a group, either.

Comment: I changed it again :)

Comment: In any event, these are two different notions of parity. The permutation $(123)$ is an even permutation, with odd order. In fact, all permutations of odd order are even permutation, but not visa versa. $(12)(34)$ is an even permutation with even order.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, is there any unified notion of parity amongst any form of Algebraic Structures? I'm still fairly juvenile in my studies (hence the name), but from what I gather of the subject, we are studying the ways in which various structures operate and the similarities therein. It surprises me that this notion has not been generalized to some degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two notions of parity you've brought up are really unrelated. In fact the "parity" of $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not intrinsic to that group in any way. You could have labeled the elements of $\langle \mathbb{Z}, \cdot \rangle$ however you liked, not even necessarily with numbers, as long as the binary operation works out the same way. You could have called the multiplicative identity $\mathfrak{I}$ if you wanted, or $\ddot\smile$. What would the parity of the identity be then?

Comment: You're completely right! I'm still taking the undergraduate course in Algebraic structures and wasn't sure if there was a "higher" notion of parity amongst arbitrary groups.

Answer (score 2):

By Cayley's theorem, each group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $H$ of a symmetric group. Each subgroup of a group is itself a group. The parity of the identity in $H$ is always even (as a permutation).